# IBM DB2 API Call Error: HWCBAS0050E: An unexpected error occurred

Tags: curl, db2, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the IBM Cloud Db2 API to list all my schemas (a simple use of the API), but I'm getting an unexpected internal error, and I can't find a way to figure it out.

The documentation link: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/db2-warehouse-on-cloud/db2-warehouse-on-cloud-v4#listdatabaseschemas

Command:

```
curl -X GET \
   https://{HOSTNAME}/dbapi/v4/schemas \
   -H 'authorization: Bearer {AUTH_TOKEN}'\
   -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

Error:

```
{"trace":"cbce96519a8abb122fee2c644b8a4ff2","errors":[{"code":"internal_server_error","message":"HWCBAS0050E: An unexpected error occurred. Please contact the administrator or refer to log files for more details.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}%
```

Comment: I doubt anyone apart from IBM Support can answer your question; have you tried contacting them?